# Makefile dependency from a variable that is reset in another file

Tags: makefile

Given this `Makefile` (stripped down to a minimal example):

```
include Makefile2
NAME=bar
```

And a second `Makefile2` with some general rules:

```
NAME=foo
something: $(NAME).txt
    @echo  $(NAME).txt
```

Calling `make something` will depend on `foo.txt` but it will print `bar.txt`.

Is it possible to define a rule in `Makefile2` that depends on `$(NAME).txt` with the actual value of `NAME`, so the example rule would use `bar.txt` as dependency also?

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack, but it works:

```
NAME:=foo

something:
    @$(MAKE) -s other OTHERNAME=$(NAME)

other: $(OTHERNAME).txt
    @echo NAME is $(NAME).txt, and this rule depends on $<
```

Comment: Well, this hack requires to pass *all* variables to the second call of `$(MAKE)` - very inconvenient if you have defined many variables. But thanks anyway!